# Duda sobre la implementación de Colecciones en java

Tags: java, colecciones

Una duda a la hora de crear una Colección en java, por ejemplo una Lista se pondría de la siguiente manera: `List <Object> milista = new ArrayList<>();`

​Porque no se podría poner de esta manera: `ArrayList <Object> milista = new ArrayList<>();`

​Se que List es la interfaz y arrayList es la clase que la implementa, pero no se porque se pone de esa manera , ya que cualquier objeto en java de normal se usa el nombre de la clase a ambos lados del igual, por ejemplo: `Persona p = new Persona();`

Comment: Cuando haces uso de una interfaz no te preocupas por la implementación, así que si tienes varios métodos con parámetros de tipo `List<Object>` no necesitas *preocuparte* por cambiar el *tipo* del parámetro si es que llegaras a cambiar de implementación, como por ejemplo, al principio pudiera usar un **ArrayList** (se lo implementa como un *array*), pero en un futuro, pudiese cambiar a un **LinkedList** (se lo implementa como una lista doblemente enlazada).

Comment: Esta es una ventaja sobre el uso de la *interfaz*, ya que no hay la necesidad de hacer un cambio entre todo el código si es que existiera alguna modificación.

Comment: Grande, me has ayudado a ver la utilidad de emplear el List<Object> , en lugar del ArrayList<Object>de la clase. Gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score -1):

*Por lo general cuando se usan las interfaces, es porque en ella tenemos lo metodos que queremos ejecutar. Puede que recomienden la interfaz para asegurarse el uso adecuado de las cosas que ofrece. Si usas arrayList puedes hacer el uso también pero en la clase pueden haber muchas cosas que en la interfáz no y no se espera el uso en ciertos aspectos.*

*Te dejo el siguiente link para que puedas ver con mejor claridad una comparación entre ambos.*

[List VS ArrayList](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-list-and-arraylist-in-java.html)

*Espero te sirva*

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, estaba pensando en eso también (en que la interfaz es la que tiene registrados los métodos y la clase que los implementan tiene esos y otros más, y podría haber "interferencias") pero no lo tenía claro.

Comment: La respuesta pudiera ser mejor si incluyes algún ejemplo donde se demuestre el *uso de la interfaz*..